# Java language features which have no equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, java

Having mostly worked with C#, I tend to think in terms of C# features which aren't available in Java. After working extensively with Java over the last year, I've started to discover Java features that I wish were in C#. Below is a list of the ones that I'm aware of. Can anyone think of other Java language features which a person with a C# background may not realize exists?

The articles http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C_Sharp give a very extensive list of differences between Java and C#, but I wonder whether I missed anything in the (very) long articles. I can also think of one feature (covariant return type) which I didn't see mentioned in either article.

Please limit answers to language or core library features which can't be effectively implemented by your own custom code or third party libraries.

1. Covariant return type - a method can be overridden by a method which returns a more specific type. Useful when implementing an interface or extending a class and you want an overriding method to return a type more specific to your class. This can be simulated using explicit interface implementation in C#, but there's no simple equivalent when overriding class methods.
2. Enums are classes - an enum is a full class in java, rather than a wrapper around a primitive like in .Net. Java allows you to define fields and methods on an enum.
3. Anonymous inner classes - define an anonymous class which implements a method. Although most of the use cases for this in Java are covered by delegates in .Net, there are some cases in which you really need to pass multiple callbacks as a group. It would be nice to have the choice of using an anonymous inner class.
4. Checked exceptions - I can see how this is useful in the context of common designs used with Java applications, but my experience with .Net has put me in a habit of using exceptions only for unrecoverable conditions. I.E. exceptions indicate a bug in the application and are only caught for the purpose of logging. I haven't quite come around to the idea of using exceptions for normal program flow.
5. strictfp - Ensures strict floating point arithmetic. I'm not sure what kind of applications would find this useful.
6. fields in interfaces - It's possible to declare fields in interfaces. I've never used this.
7. static imports - Allows one to use the static methods of a class without qualifying it with the class name. I just realized today that this feature exists. It sounds like a nice convenience.

Comment: I hope this is an improvement over my last version of this question (not relevant if you don't know what I'm talking about). There was one answer which I thought was pretty good and might have marked as the answer.

Comment: +1 for making the effort to reword.

Comment: If lack of error prone features is a feature, then java does not support 'unsafe', however java has jni support which is a round about way :)

Comment: great investigation. so far java has such features above c# that no one needs :)

Comment: On a more serious note, this is an interesting question, beyond the practical "checklist", it would be interesting to see if these differences were purposely introduced or merely reflect some lag in adoptions of various features of the language and core libraries.

Comment: @mjv: for that you'd need a timeline of when features were added/removed. Could make for a neat graph!

Comment: I'm surprised that still nobody mentioned about 'should be marked as a community wiki'.

Comment: @Roman - can I do that retroactively?

Comment: "I haven't quite come around to the idea of using exceptions for normal program flow" - and you generally don't want to. You can certainly catch and recover from many exceptions. Use them to report execution failures.

Comment: @Andrey enum as class are a great feature, replacing long switch statements with things like myEnumInstance.callFunctionForValue(this); looks cleaner

Comment: @josefx could you give link to full example?

Comment: For the usefulness of strictftp, it has to be used everywhere where results have to be reproduced or where you want to rely on the floating point standard.  
I once had a bug where two different systems using the same software produced different results. The bug was strictftp or rather lack of it in combination with different cpus.  
Also the whole java Math class uses strict floating point since some processors mess up sin and cos related functions for bigger values.

Comment: @Andrey not quite the same is i was referring to, but still a nice example for state logic in java enums http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2005/01/31/implementing-state-design-pattern-using-enums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's generics allow type wildcards. For example, `<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T Collections.max(Collection<? extends T>) { ... }` is not expressable in C#.

Comment: It's definitely a feature. It may be a feature required as a workaround some other missing feature (like anonymous inner classes are required to make up for not having closures), but it is a feature nonetheless.

Comment: This seems like the one most likely to be useful.

Answer (score 5):

Java has packages that reflect a hierarchy and filesystem layout, while in C# the assemblies are irrespective of the namespace hierarchy.

Comment: a package is also independent of its classpath. Quite useful to keep tests separated from implementation code, as package visibility is enough to test internal classes and still hides them from users.

Answer (score 3):

Octal literals! :D

`int x = 0245; System.out.println(x);`

165 is outputted. Fun :)

Comment: I did not realize this until today. It looks like in C# if you try C-style octals all it does is omit leading zeros.

Comment: I've never seen anyone used this java feature consciously. But I've seen lots of accidental errors caused by integers with leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you cannot have a return statement in a finally block.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want this in your language, but I guess Type Erasure can be seen as a feature to some.

Comment: I've seen mentions of Type Erasure as an advantage, but I've never seen an explanation of why. Can you expand on the specific advantages of it?

Comment: @jthg - well the real advantage is that it doesn't break backward compatibility...

Comment: Not all "features" are advantages. :O

Comment: @jthg it makes it easier to experiment with type systems. For example, Ceylon and Scala have more complex type systems than Java because JVM type system is too primitive to serve as the common type system. In .Net world, you get generics that are a part of the CLR, but adding anything else to the type system (HKTs, dependent types) of your language feels as a hack. F* does that, but it doesn't pretend to be a general purpose language that wants to interoperate with others.